# How to calculate ages in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two TIMESTAMP columns in my table: customer_birthday and purchase_date. I want to create a query to show the number of purchases by customer age, to create a chart.

But how do I calculate ages, in years, using BigQuery? In other words, how do I get the difference in years between two TIMESTAMPs? The age calculation cannot be made using days or hours, because of leap years, so the function `DATEDIFF(<timestamp1>,<timestamp2>)` is not appropriate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the number of days it would be if all years were 365 days long, take the difference, and divide by 365. For example:

```
SELECT (day2-day1)/365 
FROM (
  SELECT YEAR(t1) * 365 + DAYOFYEAR(t1) as day1,
         YEAR(t2) * 365 + DAYOFYEAR(t2) as day2 
  FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP('20000201') as t1, 
           TIMESTAMP('20140201') as t2))
```

This returns 14.0, even though there are intervening leap years. If you want the final result as an integer instead of floating point, you can use the `INTEGER()` function to cast the result.

Note that if one of the dates is a leap day (feb 29) it will appear to be one year away from march 1, but I think this sounds like the intended behavior.

Comment: I just created [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=170) on their issue tracker to ask for more date calculation functions, including the difference in years between two dates.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I'd really love BigQuery to have a function which calculates current age based on a date. That seems to be like a very common use case and it's not really easy due to the whole leap year thing.

I found a great article about this issue: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-accurately-calculate-age-in-bigquery-999a8417e973

Their final approach is similar to Lars Haugseth's and Saad's answer, but they do not use the DAYOFYEAR part in order to avoid issues with leap years. It also gives you the flexibility not only to calculate the current age, but also the age at a particular date that you pass to the function as argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION workspace.age_calculation(as_of_date DATE, date_of_birth DATE)
AS (
DATE_DIFF(as_of_date,date_of_birth, YEAR) - 
IF(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_birth)*100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_of_birth) > 
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM as_of_date)*100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM as_of_date)
   ,1,0)
)
```

Comment: I vote for this answer. This handles leap year as well.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the difference between dates - you could consider user-defined functions (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) with a JavaScript date library, such as Datejs or Moment.js

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_DIFF` to get the difference in years, but need to subtract by one if the birthday has not yet occured this year:

```
IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) < EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM birthdate),
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate, YEAR) - 1,
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate, YEAR)) AS age
```

Comment: This approach will not work if the birth date is in a leap year

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in a user defined function:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION calculateAge(birthdate DATE) AS (
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, birthdate, YEAR) + 
  IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) < EXTRACT(DAYOFYEAR FROM birthdate), -1, 0) -- subtract 1 if bithdate has not yet occured this year
);
```

Comment: Please note that this will not be correct for birth dates in leap years if current date is march or later. The dates starting in march will have a dayofyear value of +1 in a leap year compared to the dates in regular years due to the 29th February that only exists in leap year. Also the other way round (birthday in regular year, current year is a leap year) will not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to calculate age that takes leap years into account is to:

1. Calculate simple age based on difference in year
2. Either subtract 1 or not by:

   1. Add difference in years to birthday (e.g. if today is 2022-12-14 and birthday is 2000-12-30, then the "new" birthday becomes 2022-12-30)
   2. Do a DAY-based difference between today and "new" birthday, which either gives you a positive number (birthday passed for this year) or negative number (still has birthday this year)
   3. Subtract 1 year from simple age calculation if number is negative

In BigQuery SQL code this looks like:

```sql
SELECT
  bd AS birthday
  ,today
  ,DATE_DIFF(today, bd, YEAR) AS simpleAge
  ,DATE_DIFF(today, bd, YEAR) +
    (CASE
      WHEN DATE_DIFF(today, DATE_ADD(bd, INTERVAL DATE_DIFF(today, bd, YEAR) YEAR), DAY) >= 0
      THEN 0
      ELSE -1
    END) AS age
FROM
  (SELECT
    PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", "2000-12-01") AS bd
    ,CURRENT_DATE("Asia/Tokyo") AS today
  )
```

Outputs:

| birthday | today | simpleAge | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-12-30 | 2022-12-14 | 22 | 21 |